# Is there a way to tell conan to use different cmake executable durning conan install?

Tags: cmake, conan

When I install dependencies using `conan install --build=missing` conan executes `cmake` executable to build them if they are missing. But if I have two different versions of cmake installed in the system, `cmake` and `cmake3`, what can I do to force conan to use `cmake3` binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out. You can set an environment variable `CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM` to tell conan to use different cmake executable.

https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/7387805817aa50ad8545549b66be725f38ddb143/conans/client/build/cmake.py#L52

Comment: Nice you found the solution. You could also try, as a different approach, to define your environment, like the PATH environment variable, so it contains first the path to the cmake you want to execute. (env-vars can be defined in profiles too, even per-package, so in theory you might also be able to run different cmakes for different packages). Also, don't hesitate to use github issues for questions and other discussions.

Comment: @drodri The PATH method didn't work for me, because then Conan looked for other stuff in non-existent locations. But setting CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM to a newer binary release worked.